# Get each field as an option of an optional object

Tags: scala

I have a case class looks like this

```
case class EmotionData(
      fearful: Double,
      angry: Double,
      sad: Double,
      neutral: Double,
      disgusted: Double,
      surprised: Double,
      happy: Double
    )
```

I receive an `Option[EmotionData]` and I need each emotion data as an Option[Double].

What I did was:

```
val (fearful, angry, sad, neutral, disgusted, surprised, happy) = videoResult.emotion match {
        case Some(e) => (Some(e.fearful), Some(e.angry), Some(e.sad), Some(e.neutral), Some(e.disgusted), Some(e.surprised), Some(e.happy))
        case None => (None, None, None, None, None, None, None)
      }
```

This way I have each field as an Option[Double] value.

But isn't there a way to do this in Scala where I can iterate through all fields of an object and extract them without rewriting each field?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly different approach that might be, perhaps, a *little* more palatable.

```
val vidEmo :Option[EmotionData] = videoResult.emotion

val (fearful, angry, sad, neutral, disgusted, surprised, happy) =
  (vidEmo.map(_.fearful)
  ,vidEmo.map(_.angry)
  ,vidEmo.map(_.sad)
  ,vidEmo.map(_.neutral)
  ,vidEmo.map(_.disgusted)
  ,vidEmo.map(_.surprised)
  ,vidEmo.map(_.happy))
```

But really, you should just keep `vidEmo` around and extract what you need when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to iterate through the fields of an object by using `productIterator`. It would look something like this:

```
val List(fearful, angry, sad, neutral, disgusted, surprised, happy) =
  videoResult.emotion.map(_.productIterator.map(f => Some(f.asInstanceOf[Double])).toList)
    .getOrElse(List.fill(7)(None))
```

As you can see, this isn't much better than what you already have, and is more prone to error. The problem is that the number and order of fields is explicit in the result you have specified, so there are limits to how much this can be automated. And this only works because the type of all the fields is the same.

Personally I would keep the value as `Option[EmotionData]` as long as possible, and pick out individual values as needed, like this:

```
val opt = videoResult.emotion

val fearful = opt.map(_.fearful) // Option[Double]
val angry = opt.map(_.angry) // Option[Double]
val sad = opt.map(_.sad) // Option[Double]

val happy = opt.fold(0)(_.happy) // Double, default is 0 if opt is None

val ok = opt.forall(e => e.happy > e.sad) // True if emotion not set or more happy than sad

val disgusted = opt.exists(_.disgusted > 1.0) // True if emotion is set and disgusted value is large
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
case class EmotionData(
                        fearful: Double,
                        angry: Double,
                        sad: Double,
                        neutral: Double,
                        disgusted: Double,
                        surprised: Double,
                        happy: Double
                      )

val s = Some(EmotionData(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
val n:Option[EmotionData] = None

val emotionsOpt = s.map { x =>
  x.productIterator.toVector.map(x => Some(x.asInstanceOf[Double]))
}.getOrElse(List.fill(7)(None))

// Or if you want an iterator:
val emotionsOptItr = n.map { x =>
  x.productIterator.map(x => Some(x.asInstanceOf[Double]))
}.getOrElse(List.fill(7)(None))


println(emotionsOpt)
println(emotionsOptItr)
```

Which results in:

```
Vector(Some(1), Some(2), Some(3), Some(4), Some(5), Some(6), Some(7))
List(None, None, None, None, None, None, None)
```

Comment: Why the negative votes? could you please explain why? and then I could try to improve the answer.

Comment: Your original answer was downvoted because it was very poor. You improved it a bit after other answers had been posted, but you still don't return the `Option[Double]` values in the case where `s` is `None`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do Something like that:

```
val defaultEmotionData=(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)

object Solution1 extends App{
 case class EmotionData(
                          fearful: Double,
                          angry: Double,
                          sad: Double,
                          neutral: Double,
                          disgusted: Double,
                          surprised: Double,
                          happy: Double
                        )

  case class EmotionDataOption(
                                fearfulOpt: Option[Double],
                                angryOpt: Option[Double],
                                sadOpt: Option[Double],
                                neutralOpt: Option[Double],
                                disgustedOpt: Option[Double],
                                surprisedOpt: Option[Double],
                                happyOpt: Option[Double]
                              )

  val emotion = Some(EmotionData(1.2, 3.4, 5, 6, 7.8, 3, 12))

  val ans: EmotionDataOption = emotion.getOrElse(defaultEmotionData).toOption

  implicit class ToOption(emotionData: EmotionData) {
    def toOption = EmotionDataOption(Some(emotionData.fearful), Some(emotionData.angry), Some(emotionData.sad), Some(emotionData
        .neutral), Some(emotionData.disgusted), Some(emotionData.surprised), Some(emotionData.happy))
  }
}
```

Now where ever you will have an object of type EmotionData you can use toOption on that and it will convert it's values into EmotionDataOption which will have values Option[Double].

If you will return `Tuple7` then it will be tough to access values, that's why I think converting it into another `case class EmotionDataOption` is a good idea  and you will be able to access the values easily with the parameter name.

Comment: If you get a downvote, the first thing to do is to check whether you gave a clean and simple answer to the question. Your solution is over-complicated, it does not give the right answer, and does not "iterate through all fields of an object". The real question is why did it get upvotes?!

Comment: @Tim thank you for responding. Actually if you read the whole question it says isn’t there a way to do this in scala where author can iterate over fields of an object and extract them “WITHOUT REWRITING EACH FIELD”. And as we can see author is just proposing he doesn’t know there is that kind of way or not it’s just a thought from him he is not sure and I believe there can be multiple answers for a question. And my answer solve the purpose, I don’t find iterating good for the scenario. And can you please tell me how the answer is over complicated?

Comment: Your answer is 16 lines and gives the wrong answer, mine is 3 lines.

Comment: 1st of all it doesn’t give the wrong answer and the 2nd thing it’s not about LOC and the third thing is your 3 line of code is not reusable and if you really see my answer the part in the implicit class does the work and the other things are for making things easy like another case class and if you see that implicit class it is of 3 lines I just put everything into the same object so that if author want to check the solution he can directly run it. So it’s also a 3 line solution. I think you are new to scala. @Tim

Comment: @Tim and what if we have 1000 such object in the current condition we will have to write 3000 LOC by your solution and for mine it will still be 3 as me and 16 as you lines of code

Comment: Look at the OP solution when the `Option[EmotionData]` is `None` and compare it with your solution. And look at the line that says "I receive an `Option[EmotionData]` and I need each emotion data as an `Option[Double]`"

Comment: @Tim this is what he tried he wants a better solution otherwise he has no need to put the question on the stackoverflow.